# Firebase Return Boolean on Function as Condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I have a function on my firebase cloud function which used to check if the key exists or not :

```
function inDB(path, k){
    var exists;
    var query = ref.child(path).orderByKey();
    var promise = query.once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasChild(k.toString())) exists = true;
        else exists = false;
        return exists;
    });
    return promise;
   //return exist;
}
```

How do i use its return as condition such as for if or while, i.e :

```
var r = 0;
do{
    r = randomInt(0,2);
} while(inDB('/Numbers/',r));
ref.child('/Numbers/'+r).set("value");
```

I noticed that actually i need to wait promise fulfilled. When i run inDB function, it returned with "undefined". Several question might be same about key exists, but i still don't understand how i use the return as condition or how to handle this.
Thank you very much for all helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about you make the method signature receive callback?

```
function inDB(path, k, callback){
    var exists;
    var query = ref.child(path).orderByKey();
    var promise = query.once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasChild(k.toString())) exists = true;
        else exists = false;
        callback(exists);
        return exists;
    });
    return promise;
}
```

and call it like

```
var a = function(exists){
    r = randomInt(0,2);
    if(r%2==0 && !exists){//or some logic you want to call inDB again
       inDB('/Numbers/',r, a));
    }
}
inDB('/Numbers/',r, a));
```

i'm not sure is it the proper way to do it or not
or is there any thing in the promise that can be used to chain method after something was returned like doOnNext in RxJava

hopefully this will help you out